# SQL sliding window aggregation (without using window function)

Tags: sql, window-functions, sliding-window, analytic-functions

I am looking for a query that can aggregate data on a 21 days back basis in the following way:
my table has the following columns:
accountid, date, measure

I need, for each account, date to sum(measure) for the previous 21 days back.
Any idea how to do it in pure SQL without window/analytic function ? 
(I'm writing SQL inside a BI product which does not have support in analytic functions)

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  21 days back from what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rather inefficient method uses correlated subqueries.  If you want for each entry the previous 21 days, then:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.measure)
        from t t2
        where t2.accountid = t.accountid and
              t2.date > t.date - interval '21' day
       ) as sum21
from t;
```

Not that date functions differ by database, so your particular database might have another method of subtracting 21 days.